# Validating JMS payload in Spring

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I have a simple service sending emails. It can be invoked using REST and JMS APIs. I want the requests to be validated before processing.

When I invoke it using REST I can see that `org.springframework.validation.DataBinder` invokes `void validate(Object target, Errors errors, Object... validationHints)` and then validator from Hibernate is invoked. This works as expected.

The problem is I can't achieve the same effect with JMS Listener. The listener is implemented as follows:

```js
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import our.domain.mailing.Mailing;
import our.domain.mailing.jms.api.SendEmailFromTemplateRequest;
import our.domain.mailing.jms.api.SendSimpleEmailRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@ConditionalOnProperty("jms.configuration.destination")
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Slf4j
public class SendMailMessageListener {
    Mailing mailing;

    @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.configuration.destination}")
    public void sendEmailUsingTemplate(@Valid SendEmailFromTemplateRequest request) {
        log.debug("Received jms message: {}", request);
        mailing.sendEmailTemplate(
                request.getEmailDetails().getRecipients(),
                request.getEmailDetails().getAccountType(),
                request.getTemplateDetails().getTemplateCode(),
                request.getTemplateDetails().getLanguage(),
                request.getTemplateDetails().getParameters());
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.configuration.destination}")
    public void sendEmail(@Valid SendSimpleEmailRequest request) {
        log.debug("Received jms message: {}", request);
        mailing.sendEmail(
                request.getRecipients(),
                request.getSubject(),
                request.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The methods receive payloads but they are not validated. It's Spring Boot application and I have `@EnableJms` added. Can you guide what part of Spring source code is responsible for discovering `@Validate` and handling it? If you have any hints on how to make it running I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't as the handling of `@Valid` is specific in Spring Web MVC. If you want it else where you need to add the `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.

Comment: I think it should be doable without resorting to use `MethodValidationPostProcessor`. I can see in `org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver` there is an invocation of method `void validate(Message<?> message, MethodParameter parameter, Object target)` which delegates to `validator` object which is set in constructor. Unfortunatelly, the passed validator is null and I don't know how to set it. This validator is passed from `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` where the only place where it can be set (its setter) is never invoked.

Comment: Manually add a `JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` give it a `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` which in turn has a pre-configured validator configured. This might be a nice addition in/for Spring Boot (which you seem to be using) enable validation of messages for spring-messaging .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple and was clearly described in official documentation: [29.6.3 Annotated endpoint method signature](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-method-signature). There are few things you have to do:

1. Provide configuration implementing `JmsListenerConfigurer` (add `@Configuration` class implementing this interface)
2. Add annotation `@EnableJms` on the top of this configuration
3. Create bean `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory`. It can be done in this configuration
4. Implement method `void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar)` of interface `JmsListenerConfigurer` implemented by your configuration and set `MessageHandlerMethodFactory` using the bean you've just created
5. Add `@Validated` instead of `@Valid` to payload parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Valid in your listeners. Your answer was very close to it. In the step when you create `DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory` call `.setValidator(validator)` where validator is from `org.springframework.validation`. You can configure validator like this:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean configureValidator ()
{
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

And then inject validator instance into your jms config